# Function that adds two items from a list in search of those that will match some given sum

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge

I'm doing a Daily Challenges to get better with Python. 
I completed the first challenges with a working code but I want to make sure if there's anyway to improve or optimize it.

I have a function that adds 2 items from a list in search of those that will match the already defined result.

```
def main():

  listA = [10,11,3,7]
  k = 21 

  for i in listA:
    for e in listA:
      result = i + e
      if result == k:
        print(i, '+', e, ' = ', k)
        return
main()
```

I was thinking of reducing it to:

> ```
> def main():
>   k = 21
>   listA=[10,11,3,7]
>   print (k,'=',[(i and e) for i in listA for e in listA if k==(i+e)])
> main()
> ```

… but that would print `21 = [10,11]` instead of `21 = 10 + 11`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def main():
    k = 21
    listA=[10,11,3,7]
    print (k,' = '," + ".join([str(i and e) for i in listA for e in listA if k==(i+e)]))

main()
```

This minor change to your code will do what you're after.  Put a `" + ".join( )` around your list creator and cast the `(i and e)` items to `str`, that will then join all string elements in the list together into a string with `+` as the separator (there are spaces in there, yes, and this is necessary to get the output you're after).

[Proof of Concept](https://tio.run/##RY5BCoMwFET3OcXgxgQ/0tRFoZCF5xAXggn9TZtIzKanT0UFZ/eG4THLL79i6EqZrcN34iDVU2CPh8Fdn/DhNfdm0DfSmjp6jGe/JA4Z0lO9rWuq0KBq33HzDGtOkjGFGVbBxQQGh0O0o72QHbwxkhurRqWEOI6U8gc) (via tio.run) that shows you how this will execute.

Note I also made a change to add spaces around the equals sign, indentation, and extra spacing for readability, as well as indentation standardization (4 spaces for a single indentation level).

Comment: Thanks, It worked perfectly. the .join() is that a built-in function in Python? Like append?

Comment: @Mark-AndréTremblay it's a string function, a builtin as part of the `str` datatype.  ([Python documentation for 3.7 on str.join](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) is better probably for answering your question)